# $post and Cherrypy

Tags: jquery, python, cherrypy

I'm currently working on a project where we previously used Django. However this proved a bit to heavyweight for our needs so we are shifting the project over to use cherrypy as we only really need to handle requests.

my problem is this. I have a form on the html page (index.html) when the user clicks submit the following jQuery function gets executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginform").submit(function() {
        var request_data = {username:$("#username").val(),password:"test"};
        $.post('/request',request_data, function(data) {
                                        $("#error").html(data['response']);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works fine.
The following Cherrypy method should pick up the request data but it doesn't seem to be executed. Here is the Cherrypy method for the request.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def request(self, request_data):
    print "Debug"
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return simplejson.dumps(dict(response ="Invalid username and/or password"))
```

This is only a test method and I would expect to see 'Debug' come up in the terminal window and the error message displayed on the web page after the submit button is clicked

In terminal I get this message after the request is made:

```
"POST /request HTTP/1.1" 404 1254 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1"
```

This would indicate that it can't find the request method. All I can think is it is something to do with the parameter.

As I am new to cherrypy I expect it is something simple that I am missing any pointers would be great.

PS: The following works but I need to be able to pass multiple data to cherrypy.
(The cherrypy parameter is changed to username to allow this to work)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginform").submit(function() {
        $.post('/request',{username:$("#username").val()}, function(data) {
                                        $("#error").html(data['response']);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance in this issue.

Here is my full cherrypy file.

```
import cherrypy
import webbrowser
import os
import simplejson
import sys
from backendSystem.database.authentication import SiteAuth

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), u"media")

class LoginPage(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    return open(os.path.join(MEDIA_DIR, u'index.html'))

@cherrypy.expose
def request(self, request_data):
    print "Debug"
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return simplejson.dumps(dict(response ="Invalid username and/or password"))


config = {'/media': {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': MEDIA_DIR, }}

root = LoginPage()

# DEVELOPMENT ONLY: Forces the browser to startup, easier for development
def open_page():
webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start', open_page)

cherrypy.tree.mount(root, '/', config = config)
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Comment: you should post solution as an answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have discovered the solution to this. JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginform").submit(function() {
        $.post('/request',{username:$("#username").val(),password:"test"}, 
               function(data) {
                   $("#error").html(data['response']);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then in the cherrypy method I do this:

```
def request(self, **data):
    # Then to access the data do the following
    print data['<keyValue'] # In this example I would type print data['username']
```

Simple really, a case of not being able to see the wood for the trees. Hope this helps someone else.